# SQL Way to use IN with two columns without a JOIN

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [ID], [DESCRIPCION], [EZD]  
FROM 
    [KPTA_WEB_VW_COMBOS]
WHERE 
    [EZD] = '0000128460'
    AND [EZD] IN (SELECT DISTINCT Cod_EZD, Cod_Combo
                  FROM KPTA_REP_Venta
                  WHERE Id_Dia BETWEEN  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(MONTH, -200, GETDATE()),112) AS INT)
                               AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AS INT) 
                 )
GROUP BY 
    [ID], [DESCRIPCION], [EZD]
```

Now I have two questions, is the `IN` working with the `WHERE` clause written like that and I need to do the same for the `[ID]` column but I can't use it in the same `IN`, is there any way to do it?

The idea is to bring only the information of the `KPTA_WEB_VW_COMBOS` table only when the `[ID]` and `[EZD]` columns matches with the `KPTA_REP_Venta` table. I don't want to use `JOIN` as I don't need the data, I just want to know if the combination of those two columns exists in both tables and return what's in the `GROUP BY` clause.

EDIT:
After searching more I changed my initial query like this:

```
SELECT 
    [ID],[DESCRIPCION],[EZD]  
FROM 
    [KPTA_WEB_VW_COMBOS] A
WHERE 
    [EZD] = '0000128460' --@EZD
    AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM 
            KPTA_REP_Venta B
        WHERE 
            B.Id_Dia BETWEEN  
            CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(MONTH, -200, GETDATE()),112) AS INT) AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AS INT) 
            AND A.[EZD]= b.[Cod_Ezd]
            AND A.[ID] = b.[Cod_Combo]
    )
GROUP BY [ID],[DESCRIPCION],[EZD]
```

Comment: Your query looks a bit strange. Id_DIA sounds like an ID, but then you treat it like a string containing date information. Dates in a database should be stored in a date column. Are you confusing things here? Then you group by some values, but you are not aggregating anything. So you are actually merely doing a distinct, but then your columns include the ID, so the records are distinct already. Hence the whole GROUP BY thing doesn't make sense. Apart from that you seem to look for something like `where (col1, col2) in (select colx, coly from ...)`, is this correct?

Comment: Regarding the Id_Dia sadly, yes. Is not me, the genius that made the table made that column as int and not as Date, I don't have a say in that. 

I dont get the other part, maybe because I shouldn't use IN, maybe EXISTS? The idea is to return the info of the first table when [EZD] and [ID] Matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for something like this, where not a single column, but a list of columns shall be found with a subquery:

```
select id, descripcion, ezd  
from kpta_web_vw_combos
where (ezd, id) in
(
  select cod_ezd, cod_combo
  from kpta_rep_venta
  where id_dia between 
          cast(convert(varchar(8),dateadd(month, -200, getdate()),112) as int) and
          cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) as int) 
);
```

This is how it is donme in many DBMS, and I am pretty sure it is standard SQL, but SQL Server doesn't feature this syntax.

So re-write this with EXISTS, as you already guessed:

```
select id, descripcion, ezd  
from kpta_web_vw_combos c
where exists
(
  select *
  from kpta_rep_venta v
  where v.id_dia between 
          cast(convert(varchar(8),dateadd(month, -200, getdate()),112) as int) and 
          cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) as int) 
  and v.cod_ezd = c.ezd
  and v.cod_combo = c.id
);
```

Comment: Some people here at where I work are telling me that the convert part (I know is an atrocity to make an Int column and save dates there but I did not design the table, im just the guy who recieves a ticket and solve problems) but they are telling me that I can save those CAST(CONVERT()) in two different variables that it is faster.
Would you suggest that?

Comment: No, there is just one current date for a query. So the DBMS gets the date once and works with it. So you can consider the two date operations kind of constants for the query. Same as working with a variable; no need to explicitely use variables here hence.